# Postman Soap POST to C# Class

Tags: soap

While sending POST from Postman to VS .NET Core 7 using SoapCore values hitting Service Method are NULL. I think I am formatting the SOAP request wrong? Thanks to all who help!

MyCustomModel.cs

```
[DataContract]
public class MyCustomModel
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

SampleService.cs

```
    public class SampleService : ISampleService
{
    public string Test(string s) // This works
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Test Method Executed!");
        return s;
    }

    public void XmlMethod(XElement xml) // customModel NULL here
    {
        Console.WriteLine(xml.ToString());
    }

    public MyCustomModel TestCustomModel([FromBody] MyCustomModel customModel) // customModel NULL here
    {
        return customModel;
    }
}
```

StartUp.cs

```
    public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.TryAddSingleton<ISampleService, SampleService>();
        services.AddSoapCore();
        services.AddMvc();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseSoapEndpoint<ISampleService>("/Service.asmx", new SoapEncoderOptions(), SoapSerializer.XmlSerializer);
    }
}
```

WSDL

[image]

Postman
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The solution was  tags.[image]

What really helped me was I found this post on how to import the WSDL into Postman.

[enter link description here](https://medium.com/apis-with-valentine/how-to-import-the-wsdl-from-soap-web-service-in-postman-7a9b41424a5f#:%7E:text=Open%20Postman%20and%20click%20on,to%20your%20existing%20Postman%20collections.)

Comment: please do not use images when you can use code